# Attaching events to an groundOverlay in Google Earth Plug-in API

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to attach mouse events to an groundOverlay feature using this code:

```
     var groundOverlay = ge.createGroundOverlay('');
        var icon = ge.createIcon('');
        icon.setHref("http://www.google.com/logos/earthday08.gif");
        groundOverlay.setIcon(icon);
        var latLonBox = ge.createLatLonBox('');
        latLonBox.setBox(48.80, 48.75, -121.77, -121.85, 0);
        groundOverlay.setLatLonBox(latLonBox);
        ge.getFeatures().appendChild(groundOverlay);    

          google.earth.addEventListener(groundOverlay, 'click', function(e) { 
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log("hello"); 
                    });
```

But clicking shows no results. Any ideas why?

Thanks!
Bill

Comment: I added a late answer as I had just marked a question as a duplicate of yours. There were a couple of problems with the current answer so I added one with a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since KmlGroundOverlays do not yet generate mouse events, another work-around is to receive mouse events from the globe and then determine if the mouse is within an overlay (a ‘hit test’).  Below is a starting point for code that does that, using mouseMove events.  It generates two overlapping overlays (one rotated) and brings the overlay under the mouse to the surface (by manipulating drawingOrder).

It maintains information about the overlays in its own structures (rather than walking the KML, which might be possible).

I wasn’t able to find a way to get the locations of the vertices of a rotated overlay from GE, so rotation is done in code using a cartesian approximation.  This code might break on poles or boundaries or large polygons.

Once the vertices are known, the hit test that runs on mouse moves is based upon an excellent discussion at [How can I determine whether a 2D Point is within a Polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test)

So this code illustrates starting ideas for:

- how to synthesize mouse events from overlays (a work-around until KML overlays can generate mouse events)
- how to approximate the vertices of a rotated overlay (to find the location of an overlay)
- doing a hit test on an overlay (from the above-mentioned reference)
- using drawOrder to bring an overlapped overlay to the surface on mouseover

There’s a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/pudkg/

Here's the code & html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ge;
var overlays = [];   // record information about overlays (filled by 'addOverlay')
var drawOrder = 0;   // drawOrder value of topmost overlay
google.load("earth", "1");

function Point (lat, lon) {
  this.lat = lat;
  this.lon = lon;
}

function Overlay (groundOverlay, points, drawOrder) {
  this.overlay = groundOverlay;  // KML object
  this.points = points;          // array of Points (vertices of overlay)
  this.drawOrder = drawOrder;    // integer, higest displayed topmost
}
Overlay.prototype.hitTest = function (lat, lon) {   // return true if lat/lon is within overlay
    // Based upon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test
    var isInside = false;
    var minLon = this.points[0].lon, maxLon = this.points[0].lon;
    var minLat = this.points[0].lat, maxLat = this.points[0].lat;
    for (var n = 1; n < this.points.length; n++) {
      var q = this.points[n];
      minLon = Math.min(q.lon, minLon);
      maxLon = Math.max(q.lon, maxLon);
      minLat = Math.min(q.lat, minLat);
      maxLat = Math.max(q.lat, maxLat);
    }
    if (lon < minLon || lon > maxLon || lat < minLat || lat > maxLat)
      return false;

    var i = 0, j = this.points.length - 1;
    for (i, j; i < this.points.length; j = i++)
      if ( (this.points[i].lat > lat) != (this.points[j].lat > lat) &&
          lon < (this.points[j].lon - this.points[i].lon) * (lat - this.points[i].lat) /
          (this.points[j].lat - this.points[i].lat) + this.points[i].lon )
        isInside = !isInside;
    return isInside;
  }

function init() {
  google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
}

function initCB(e) {
  ge = e;
  ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

  var lat = 37.204193;
  var lon = -112.934429;
  var dlat = 0.003;
  var dlon = 0.005;
  var offset = 0.004;

  var la = ge.createLookAt('');  // position camera
  la.set(lat, lon, 0, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 0, 30, 2000);
  ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);

  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)  // generate two overlays, overlapping; second one rotated
    addOverlay('http://www.google.com/logos/earthday08.gif',
        lat + dlat + offset*i, lat - dlat + offset*i,
        lon + dlon + offset*i, lon - dlon + offset*i, 30*i);
  // KML overlays can't (yet) generate mouse events, so look for events from globe
  google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), 'mousemove', function(event) {
    var lat = event.getLatitude();
    var lon = event.getLongitude();
    // show that a move event was received:
    document.getElementById('logMove').innerHTML = event.getLatitude();
    topmost = -1, zMax = 0;  // find topmost overlay
    for (var i = overlays.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      if (overlays[i].hitTest(lat, lon)) {  // if mouse is within overlays[i]
        document.getElementById('logHit').innerHTML = i + '; ' + overlays[i].drawOrder;
        if (overlays[i].drawOrder > zMax) {  // if this overlay is higher than any previous
          topmost = i;
          zMax = overlays[i].drawOrder;
        }
      }
    if ((topmost >= 0) && (overlays[topmost].drawOrder < drawOrder)) {
      // if in an overlay and it is buried, make it top-most
      overlays[topmost].overlay.setDrawOrder(++drawOrder);
      overlays[topmost].drawOrder = drawOrder;  // update local structure
    }
    document.getElementById('logOver').innerHTML = topmost + '; ' + zMax;
  });
}

function addOverlay(url, north, south, east, west, rotation) {
  var groundOverlay = ge.createGroundOverlay('');  // create overlay
  var icon = ge.createIcon('');
  icon.setHref(url);
  groundOverlay.setIcon(icon);
  var latLonBox = ge.createLatLonBox('');
  latLonBox.setBox(north, south, east, west, rotation);
  groundOverlay.setLatLonBox(latLonBox);
  groundOverlay.setDrawOrder(++drawOrder);
  ge.getFeatures().appendChild(groundOverlay);
  var points = [];  // figure out lat/lon of the corners of the overlay
  var sinTheta = Math.sin(rotation * Math.PI / 180.0);
  var cosTheta = Math.cos(rotation * Math.PI / 180.0);
  // rotation is about the center of the overlay; find midpoint:
  var midPoint = new Point((north + south) / 2, (west + east) / 2);
  // To do cartesian rotation, need to consider that the distance between
  // units of longitude diminish as one goes north, to zero at pole:
  var cosLat = Math.cos(midPoint.lat * Math.PI / 180.0);  // longitude compression factor
  west = (west - midPoint.lon) * cosLat, east = (east - midPoint.lon) * cosLat;
  north -= midPoint.lat, south -= midPoint.lat;
  // use cartesian rotation (good enough approximation for UI away from pole, boundaries)
  // after rotation, restore (expand) longitudes by compression factor
  points.push(new Point(midPoint.lat + west * sinTheta + north * cosTheta,
      midPoint.lon + (west * cosTheta - north * sinTheta) / cosLat));
  points.push(new Point(midPoint.lat + east * sinTheta + north * cosTheta,
      midPoint.lon + (east * cosTheta - north * sinTheta) / cosLat));
  points.push(new Point(midPoint.lat + east * sinTheta + south * cosTheta,
      midPoint.lon + (east * cosTheta - south * sinTheta) / cosLat));
  points.push(new Point(midPoint.lat + west * sinTheta + south * cosTheta,
      midPoint.lon + (west * cosTheta - south * sinTheta) / cosLat));
  overlays.push(new Overlay(groundOverlay, points, drawOrder));
}

function failureCB(errorCode) {
  alert("GE init fail");
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id=map3d style='height: 400px; width: 600px'></div>
<p>Mouse over the two overlays.  The one under the mouse should come to surface.</p>
<p>Latitude of mouse: <span id=logMove></span></p>
<p>Index of last overlay hit; its drawOrder: <span id=logHit></span></p>
<p>Index of topmost overlay; max drawOrder: <span id=logOver></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, the code you posted is totally correct.

The `KmlGroundOverlay` object does inherit from the `GEEventEmitter` so it has the standard `KmlMouseEvents`; mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, etc.

You can see that clearly here: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_ground_overlay-members

For some reason the events just don't fire though. There is a bug report for this here (the Overlay issue was merged into it I believe...)
https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=123

As @lifeIsGood says's in his answer the best workaround is to place a transparent polygon with the same geometry under the GroundOverlay. However setting the opacity to `0`, at least programmatically, isn't a good idea. [Opacity is experimental](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/opacity.html) and at the moment if you set it to `0` for an object then the `KmlMouseEvents` generally will then not fire for that object. I believe the plugin effectively removes the feature from the event chain when it is fully transparent. Anyhow, to prevent this set the opacity to `.1` rather than `0`

A better way to handle the event on the polygon is to pass the GroundOverlay back to the handler. This way when the event is raised you have a reference to both the GroundOverlay and the event data in the handler without the need for any global variables or unique IDs. e.g.

```
// attach the event to the transparent polygon discussed
google.earth.addEventListener(polygon, 'click', function(e) {
  handler(overlay, e)
});

// handle the event.
// sender is the overlay
// event is the real KmlMouseEvent from the polygon.
function handler(sender, event) {
  console.log(sender.getType());  //KmlGroundOverlay
  console.log(event.getTarget().getType());  //KmlPolygon
};
```

[I made a working example of this here.](http://jsfiddle.net/fraser/2bUXQ/)

Comment: No worries. Just to note I also realised that the link to the bug report wasn't really applicable so I have [raised the issue properly](https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=960).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do too much too soon.
First, you need to add the event listener to the GE Plugin

so replace

```
google.earth.addEventListener(groundOverlay, 'click', function(e) {
```

with

```
google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), 'click', function(e) {
```

sometimes it is better to use `ge.getWindow()` or `ge.getView()` depending on what you are doing

EDIT: after comments pointed out error

Instead of detecting a click on the `GroundOverlay`, create a `Polygon` that covers the exact same terrain and detect a click on it instead.

When creating the `Polygon`, I would make it 'invisible' but setting the opacity to zero. Then as in my previous answer, use an unique_id when determining if it was clicked

to set a unique_id to a polygon: in the KML it looks like this

```
<Placemark id="unique_id">
<name>Polygon Name</name>
<styleUrl>....</styleUrl>
<Polygon>
  .....
</Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

then use this kind of function inside the eventListener

```
    var obj = e.getTarget();
         if (obj.getType() == 'KmlPlacemark') {
         e.preventDefault();
         var placemark = obj;
         var placemark_id = placemark.getId();
              if (placemark_id == 'unique_id') {
              console.log("hello");
              }
    }
```

I know you are able to detect a click on a `Polygon` this way, so this idea should work for `GroundOverlays`. I haven't tested it though. If you are having problems, I would suggest setting the `<drawOrder>` of the `Polygon` to a number higher than a `<drawOrder>` of the `GroundOverlay`

Hope this works!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately the getType() call always returns "GEGlobe" if it's over the overlay or not. It does return "KmlPlacemark" if I click on a placemark.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, you are correct. I now remember it was different when talking about overlays (both ground and screen). If I work out an answer I will edit mine and let you know.

Comment: I'd appreciate it. BTW: I took a look at your 3DWhistler site. Nice work!

Comment: I believe I have a working solution, see edit to my answer. Thanks for   the comment on my 3D Whistler site

Comment: Yes, that could work, but I'm surprised there is no way to detect clicks to an overlay. Seems like a design defect in the Google API? Thanks for your help!